# An Error about setting Local Property in Function with loop (Firefox and Safari)

Tags: javascript, oop, firefox, arguments

i occured a problem about code below, which i trying to set localproperties with a loop:

```
function aa(b,c,d){
    var args=arguments.callee.toString().match(/function.*\((.*)\)/)[1].split(",");
    for(var key=0;key<arguments.callee.length;key++){
        this[args[key]]=arguments[key];
    }           
    alert("this.b="+this.b+",this.c="+this.c+",this.d="+this.d);
};
var xxx=new aa(11,22,33);
```

The thing is: i get the three values correctly in IE,Chrome and Opera; but in Firefox and Safari, i only could get the first(this.b=11,in this case), while the othere two undefined. Does anyone could tell me the reason and how to fix it? thks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.split(/, */)` in line two.

`Function.prototype.toString` prettyprints in some engines:

```
js> ''+ function aa(a,b,c){}
"function aa(a, b, c) {\n}"
```